# vue missing script: sitemap

Tags: vue.js, sitemap

I am using the [vue-cli-plugin-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-sitemap) to create sitemap. I use this as a standalone plugin

```
module.exports = {
    pluginOptions: {
        sitemap: {
            urls: [
                'https://example.com/',
                'https://example.com/about',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `npm run sitemap` it throws the error:
[image: error]

What should I do to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Did you [install the plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-sitemap#installation)?

Comment: @Phil yes, of course.

Comment: Did it correctly modify your `package.json` file to add the `sitemap` script in the `scripts` section?

Comment: @Phil yes, there's this line `"vue-cli-plugin-sitemap": "^2.3.0",` on `package.json`. Btw, I've attached the full debug log on my question.

Comment: @Phil so sorry, I did not see your link there. Now it works with `vue add sitemap`. Anyway, what is the difference between `vue add sitemap` and `npm i vue-cli-plugin-sitemap`? I thought it's the same.

Comment: The latter adds a dependency without creating any runnable _scripts_. The former, as per the same documentation link above... _"will add a script called `sitemap` to your `package.json`. No other files will be modified."_

Answer (score 0):

Run command
=> vue add sitemap
Refer to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-sitemap